# Accessing JSON from Node/Express Route?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, node.js

I was wondering, since Node is written in JavaScript, and I'm using ES6 to write a little fun app, is there a way to access the object I send to the route without using ajax to get it from the server/api? In other words, can I say something like

```
import { jsonData } from '../api/server.js';
```

and then be able to use `jsonData` as a variable in my client side controller?
In other words... I would have something like this:

```
var DataController = (req, res) => {
let data_client = new DataClient();

data_client.getData().then(
    (data) => {
        res.render('index', { jsonData: jsonData });
    },
    (error) => {
        res.send('An error occurred. Please check your connection settings.');
    }
);
```

Is what I'm asking possible?
If not, would I just use an XHR request or fetch?
Just wondering what my options are since I want to use Node (4.x) to its full potential. Sorry if this question was confusing or vague.

Comment: unless server.js exports `jsonData` (which i doubt,) you'll have to get that data either by sending an http rquest to the server, or, depending on how your routes are built, by executing the route function that returns the data.

Comment: That makes sense - That's what I thought and just wanted to make sure there wasn't an easier way. It's still odd to me that Express wraps everything into an MVC framework, but then just have to remember that that's just the server. The client and API technically have "separate" apps. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that server side file will be accessible over client side.

If you make your server side file available on client and your server.js file is generic enough to run on client side as well along with correct client side export statement , then yes you can import the `jsondata` with syntax like

```
import { jsonData } from '../api/server.js';
```

and use it else where

Beware that there are limited browsers that support `import` statement

You can check the list from [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=import)

Comment: That seems risky - I think I'll go with an ajax call of some sort!

Comment: Ajax Is better,  this is the only way I can think of if you really want to avoid ajax